# Smoke (or) explosion animation while removing an item from my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, animation

I want to remove an item (lets say a UIButton) from my iPhone application. I want to add some animation when i tap on the button to remove it.

*This is the animation i want*:

```
In your OSX dock, if you right-click on an item and tap on *remove from dock*, 
it kinda like **explodes** with a funny noise, and removes itself from that dock.
```

Any knows how to do that *smoke* (or) tiny explosion animation on the iPhone ?? Is there a pre-defined name for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roll your own using CAEmitterLayer - there are lots of examples on SO and elsewhere. You could do some really nice stuff (or maybe find some really nice open source code).

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, there's an API for exactly that on Mac OS X:

```
NSPoint centrePoint = ...;
NSSize size = ...;
NSShowAnimationEffect(NSAnimationEffectPoof, centrePoint, size, nil, NULL, NULL);
```

On iOS, there isn't because the animation is a Mac-specific animation. On iOS, one typically sees the deleted object collapse into a point. That animation can be done by animating the transform of a view (using `CAAnimation` or the `UIView` class methods) so that it scales to nothingness.